# How correctly save game progress via libGDX Preferences on Android devices?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

**I am using next code.
This code work fine on desktop version, but on Android device does not.
return Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREFS_NAME) always is null.
Why? Where I could make mistake?**

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;

public class BeatlesPreferences {
    // constants
    private static final String PREF_VIBRO = "vibro";
    private static final String PREF_MUSIC_ENABLED = "musicenabled";
    private static final String PREF_SOUND_ENABLED = "soundenabled";
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "my_app";

    public BeatlesPreferences() {
    }

    protected Preferences getPrefs() {
        return Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREFS_NAME);
    }

    public boolean isSoundEffectsEnabled() {
        return getPrefs().getBoolean(PREF_SOUND_ENABLED, true);
    }

    public void setSoundEffectsEnabled(boolean soundEffectsEnabled) {
        getPrefs().putBoolean(PREF_SOUND_ENABLED, soundEffectsEnabled);
        getPrefs().flush();
    }

    public boolean isMusicEnabled() {
        return getPrefs().getBoolean(PREF_MUSIC_ENABLED, true);
    }

    public void setMusicEnabled(boolean musicEnabled) {  
        getPrefs().putBoolean(PREF_MUSIC_ENABLED, musicEnabled);
        getPrefs().flush();
    }

    public boolean isVibroEnabled() {
        return getPrefs().getBoolean(PREF_VIBRO, true);
    }

    public void setVibroEnabled(boolean vibro) {
        getPrefs().putBoolean(PREF_VIBRO, vibro);
        getPrefs().flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error stacktrace.  I suspect you're reaching `getPrefs` before Gdx.app is initialized (though that should be the similar to the desktop).  You should consider adding some `assert` checks that Gdx.app is non-null to distinguish from `getPreferences` returning null, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use like this:

```
   private Preferences preferences;
   protected Preferences getPrefs() {
      if(preferences==null){
         preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREFS_NAME);
      }
   return preferences;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting the name of the app in .prefs in any way in your code. Add the name just like you added music, vibro...etc

```
public void setPREFS_NAME() {
    getPrefs().putBoolean("PREFS_NAME", PREFS_NAME);
    getPrefs().flush();
}
```