# Check if app is opened for the first time in LIBGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, sharedpreferences

I am trying to check if the app is opened for first time in LIBGDX. I want this logic to be implemented in level selection screen. I want the sprite to get different for the first time. I have implemented the below code,

```
    private static Preferences prefs;
    public MenuScreen(MyGame game) {
         prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("firsttimeopen");
            if (prefs.getBoolean("lock",true) ) {
            prefs.putBoolean("lock", false);
            Gdx.app.log("firsttimeopening" + a, "firsttimeopening" + a);
             } else {
        Gdx.app.log("secondtimeopening" + a, "secondtimeopening" + a);
           }
```

Here both the condition becomes true when i open the app.I don't know where did I go wrong. I even referred this question [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612619/how-correctly-save-game-progress-via-libgdx-preferences-on-android-devices) and even this question [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used)but nothing helped. Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you forget to add SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
           prefs.putBoolean("lock", false);
          editor.commit();

Comment: It throws error saying "cannot resolve symbol SharedPreferences" @saeed

Comment: I tried changing it to Preferences from SharedPreferences but it throws error saying "cannot resolve symbol editor" @saeed

Comment: @saeed, you're wrong since @anusha is using `libgdx`. Check the answer to find the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences):

> Your changes to a preferences instance will only get persisted if you explicitly call the flush() method.

Add the line in your code:

```
prefs.putBoolean("lock", false);
prefs.flush();
```